# solving exponential equation gives more than one solution

Tags: python, sympy, equation

I have code below for a simple test of `sympy.solve`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x', real=True)
#expr = sympify('exp(1 - 10*x) - 15')

expr = exp(1 - x) - 15
print "Expressiong:", expr
out = solve(expr)
for item in out:
    print "Answer:", item

expr = exp(1 - 10*x) - 15
print expr
out = solve(expr)
for item in out:
    print "Answer:", item
```

output is as follows:

```
Expressiong: exp(-x + 1) - 15
Answer: -log(15) + 1
exp(-10*x + 1) - 15
Answer: log(15**(9/10)*exp(1/10)/15)
```

The equation `exp(1 - x) = 15` is solved correctly (`x = -15log(15) + 1`).

But when I change `x` to `10*x`, the result is weird.

1. Why would there be a lot of complex answers if I initialize the symbol `x` without `real=True`?
2. Even with `real=True` when initializing the symbol `x`, the answer still is not correct. Comparing to the first equation, the result should be `-3/2*log(15) + 1/10`. Did I write the equation wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I can also confirm that the `solve` output for the equation `exp(1 - 10*x) - 15 == 0` appears unecessarily complicated. I would suggest for univariate equations to first consider `sympy.solveset`. For this example, it gives the following nicely formatted solutions.

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing(pretty_print=True)

x = sp.symbols('x')

sp.solveset(sp.exp(1 - 10*x) - 15,x)
```

[image]

Note that there are complex roots due to the exponential function being multi-valued (in complex domain). If you want to restrict the domain of the solution to reals, `solveset` has the convenient option `domain` for this purpose.

```
sp.solveset(sp.exp(1 - 10*x) - 15,x, domain = sp.S.Reals)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`solve` gives real and complex roots if symbols allow. An equation like `exp(2*x)-4` can be though of as `y**2 - 4` with `y = exp(x)` and `y` (thus `x`) will have two solutions. There are 10 solutions if the 2 is replaced with 10. (But there are actually many more solutions besides as `solveset` indicates.)

You based your expectation of the 2nd case on a misstatement of the solution for the first case which was actually `-log(15) + 1`; the second case correctly gives 1/10th that value.